# Find Text Node with largest number of elements preceeding

Tags: xslt

With XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <A>
        <B>
            <C>
                <Name>Bob</Name>
            </C>
            <D>
                <Operation>Yes</Operation>
                <E>
                    <Operation>No</Operation>
                </E>
            </D>
        </B>
    </A>
</Root>
```

I have XSLT that produces text output:

> /Root/A/B/C/Name
>       /Root/A/B/D/Operation
>       /Root/A/B/D/E/Operation

Problem:
The deepest text node is /Root/A/B/D/E/Operation.

I'd like to be able to arrive at the number 5 (the text node with the largest / max number of element levels in front, prior to producing the output above.

So it should work for any XML document. Element names are unknown.

Comment: If you have XSLT code that you expect us to adapt or enhance then please show it as a minimal but complete and well-formatted code sample in your question. Also tell us which version of XSLT you use. I don't see how `/Root/A/B/D/E/Operation` selects or, like you say, "is the deepest text node", that path selects `Operation` element nodes, not text nodes. So you need to clarify that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT 3 stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="let $leaf-elements := //*[not(*)], 
                                $max-anc := max($leaf-elements/count(ancestor::*))
                            return ($max-anc, $leaf-elements!string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(), '/'))" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

run against your sample input outputs

```
5
Root/A/B/C/Name
Root/A/B/D/Operation
Root/A/B/D/E/Operation
```

Online sample https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwh.